# What is the difference between the Tor browser initiated by Firefox v68.9.0esr and Brave Version 1.10.97 Chromium: 83.0?

Tags: configuration, firefox, browsers

I'm using Tor browser initiated through Firefox v68.9.0esr and Brave Version 1.10.97 Chromium: 83.0 interchangeably for quite some time now.

While automating I'm able to able to start a Mozilla based *TOR* browser using
[Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/) but as a *proof of concept* I want to start a *Brave* browser based *TOR* enabled session.

I know there are some difference but I'm yet to come to a conclusion about the difference between the two configuration / implementation. Can someone help me out please?

Snapshot of Tor browser initiated by Firefox v68.9.0esr:

[image: tor_esr]

Snapshot of Tor browser initiated by Brave Version 1.10.97 Chromium: 83.0:

[image: tor_brave]

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for here? Both browsers are designed for different purposes. Brave is designed for privacy, while Tor is designed for anonymity. You might also be interested in the Tor Browser design doc: https://2019.www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/

Comment: @Steve I understand both _Mozilla_ and _Chromium_ have a different browsing engine. I was looking at, how they are implemented, if any fundamental difference as both uses the _TOR_ bundle. Of coarse the design doc you shared is pretty much interesting.

Comment: They are two absolutely different browsers with absolutely different engines. Can you specify what exactly are you searching for in the implementations of these browsers?

Comment: @NeverMine17 Any of the existing difference(s) would help me to get started.

Comment: @DebanjanB I understand, but you would really help people that would answer your question to be more specific.

Comment: @NeverMine17 I'm new to _TOR_ stackexchange, I am not sure what else should I mention to keep the question short and precise. I use [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:7429447+[selenium]) and [tor](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:7429447+[tor]) extensively with _Mozilla Firefox_, _Firefox Nightly_, _Firefox Development_, _Chrome_ and _Brave_. I will be happy to clarify, if someone can point me what exactly I need to add.

Comment: @NeverMine17 Updated the question with more information about my usecase.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been [answered](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/21244/tor-vs-brave-which-is-technically-more-effective-to-hinder-user-tracking-fin) but because you have a bounty, I can't mark it as such.

From [Brave](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/wiki/Fingerprinting-Protections):

> Brave includes best-effort defense against browser fingerprinting.
> Broadly speaking, browser fingerprinting is the detection of browser
> and operating system features that differ between users for the
> purpose of covertly identifying users and tracking them across the
> web. Although fingerprinting attacks will always be possible, it is
> worthwhile for us to make these attacks as slow / costly / difficult
> as possible.
>
> Brave includes two types of fingerprinting protections, (i) blocking,
> removing or modifying APIs, to make Brave instances look as similar as
> possible, and (ii) randomizing values from APIs, to prevent cross
> session and site linking (e.g. making Brave instances look different
> to websites each time).
>
> In cases where we block, remove or modify API behavior, we attempt to
> return empty, or non-identifying values, that have the "shape" of
> expected values, to minimize web compatibility issues.
>
> In cases where we randomize API values, we attempt to make
> modifications that are imperceivable to humans, but distinguishing to
> computers / fingerprinters. These randomization values are derived
> from a seed that changes per session, and per eTLD+1. Third party
> frames and script share the seed value of the top level, eTLD+1
> domain. This approach is especially useful in fingerprinters that hash
> together a large number of semi-identifiers into a single identifier,
> since randomizing just one value "poisons" the entire fingerprint.

Tor takes a different approach. It seeks to make everyone look exactly the same. If you modify the Tor Browser with addons, etc, you start to look different to a web server and therefore you are more easily picked out.

Tor Browser is dedicated to Anonymity. That is its single goal.
Brave is a general purpose browser and is not dedicated to anonymity.